# How to import files from other directory in Scala?

Tags: scala, import, directory, compilation, subdirectory

I have dir hierarchy such as this:

```
src
src/Model
src/View
src/Controller
```

Now I want to built my application. How can I import/include classes from Model View and Controller, becouse compiler can't see them?

// edit

src/App.scala

```
import swing._

object App extends Application {

  val model       = new Model
  val view        = new View(model)
  val controller  = new Controller(model, view)

  view.visible = true

}
```

src/Model/Model.scala

```
class Model {
  // some code
}
```

src/View/View.scala

```
import swing._

class View(model:Model) extends MainFrame {
  // some code
}
```

src/Controller/Controller.scala

```
class Controller(model:Model, view:View) {
  // some code
}
```

Here is a build script

```
#!/bin/bash

source ${0%/*}/config.inc.sh

if [ ! -d $CLASSES_PATH ]; then
  notice "Creating classes directory..."
  mkdir $CLASSES_PATH
fi

notice "Building VirtualCut..."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/Model/*.scala -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (Model)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/View/*.scala -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (View)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/Controller/*.scala -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (Controller)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/*.scala -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed."
success "Building complete."

exit 0
```

Everything works fine when all files are in src dir.

Comment: -1 Insufficient detail. Please show the contents of some files and the details of how you are trying to compile this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use a grown up build tool, instead of messing around with hand-rolled shell scripts.  SBT has got to be your best bet here.
2. At the top of each source file, specify what package it should belong in. It's ill-advised to just dump everything in the default package - a guaranteed recipe for future namespace conflicts.
3. Make sure that each file also `import`s classes that it has a dependency on.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not reported what error you are getting, we are left to guess. However, the basic error seems to be simply that you are compiling code that reference each other in different steps. The solution is simple: don't do that. Do this:

```
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/Model/*.scala $SOURCE_PATH/View/*.scala $SOURCE_PATH/Controller/*.scala $SOURCE_PATH/*.scala -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed."
success "Building complete."
```

If, however, you are sure there are no cross dependencies, you need to pass the CLASSES_PATH as classpath:

```
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/Model/*.scala-d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (Model)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/View/*.scala -cp $CLASSES_PATH -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (View)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/Controller/*.scala -cp $CLASSES_PATH -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed (Controller)."
scalac $SOURCE_PATH/*.scala -cp $CLASSES_PATH -d $CLASSES_PATH || error "Build failed."
```